# Way to Serializing / Deserializing XSD with different version namespaces?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Is there any way to allow serializing / deserializing to XML with a preferred namespace and using an alternative if it fails?

To be more specific, I have an XSD defined with segments as below...

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.PrimaryNameSpaceV2.com"
   xmlns="http://www.PrimaryNameSpaceV2.com"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:xsi ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   elementFormDefault="qualified"
   attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

It has generated for me class definitions that contain the following...

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute("MyObject", Namespace="http://www.PrimaryNameSpaceV2", AnonymousType=true)]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("MyObject", Namespace="http://www.PrimaryNameSpaceV2")]
```

Now I have no issues when serializing data that comes in with the header containing the following

```
<xmlns="http://www.PrimaryNameSpaceV2.com">
```

That comes at no surprise.  However I get errors for unexpected content when the namespace is of a prior version.  This is also no surprise to me since clearly the namespaces are different. V2 vs V1.

```
<xmlns="http://www.PrimaryNameSpaceV1.com">
```

I'd like to be able to serialize and deserialize with PrimaryNameSpaceV2 and if PrimaryNameSpaceV2 fails, try with PrimaryNameSpaceV1.  But I'm not exactly sure if there's any way of doing this short of creating an entirely new xsd, as well as an entire new set of class definitions.  Is there no concise way of supporting both versions of these namespaces?
Apologies if there is some basic versioning information that supports this but I was having trouble finding any resources for such an operation.

Comment: You can use xml linq.  You can get default namespace using XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename); XElement root = doc.Root; XNameSpace ns = root.GetDefaultNameSpace();

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend transforming the input XML into a consistent form before you do any other processing, typically by adding an XSLT step to your processing pipeline. Similarly, handle variations in output formats by a final post-processing step on the output pipeline.